# Do any open-source standalone restful image servers exist?

Tags: image, image-processing, nginx, gridfs

I'm planning to develop a standalone restful Image Server with the following functionality, but first would like to know if something similar already exists in the open source world (language not important):

- restful (crud) on master image, e.g: `/GET/asd983249as`
- possibly bulk-gets / LIST
- support for metadata (Creative commons info, dimensions, etc.) that directly relates to the image (references from the domain to these images is NOT included)
- restful lazy-get of different 'renditions' of an image. i.e if a rendition doesn't exist, it is created upon request. Obviously the original image needs to exist. Different operations are allowed (resize and crop to begin with)
- e.g: `/GET/asd983249as/100x100` (simple resize)
- allowed dimensions are configurable, so not to get DoS'ed (not as quickly anyway)

Non functional:

- Reasonable performant / Scalable  / HA (yeah I know this doesn't say anything really)
- Possibly in-mem caching

Thinking about going the Mongo GridFS route, getting  MongoDb sharding and replication almost for free. Putting Nginx in front, perhaps (in part) directly using nginx-gridfs (see below) should allow for the rest-stuff and, with some config, some simple caching if gridfs can't handle that for itself (don't know)

**Sources:**

nginx-gridfs
http://www.coffeepowered.net/2010/02/17/serving-files-out-of-gridfs/

Idea of lazy-gets (and a simple implementation of what I'm looking for, although it seemed more hobbyish than an actively maintained project)
http://sumitbirla.com/2011/11/how-to-build-a-scalable-caching-resizing-image-server/

other stuff that comes close, but isn't an end solution
https://github.com/adamdbradley/foresight.js/wiki/Server-Resizing-Images

Anything that already does this?

Comment: why the downvote? References to existing open source libraries can hardly be considered to solicite debate, etc.?

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend you this project:
https://github.com/imbo/imbo

Its easy to use, stable and used in big projects.

But I am still curious about alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for options for a project, and I found those two below. They are not a perfect match to your requirements but seem quite mature. I have no experience with them yet, though.

1. https://imageresizing.net/ Essential edition is open source. The more advanced solutions are not.
2. http://thumborize.me/ (with associated [github](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor)) has many interesting features like face detection, new codecs, smart cropping.